# Is there a way of passing all the defined variables to a GroovyShell?

Tags: binding, groovy, eval

Right now, when I'm trying to eval a piece of code in Groovy, I have to do something like this :

```
new GroovyShell(new Binding([var1:var1])).evaluate(line)
```

This can be pretty nasty when you have a lot of variables defined. Is there a better way of doing this? Is there something like Python's `locals`, or something similar that lists all the declared variables?

Comment: You need variables that declared within groovy shell instance?

Comment: I need access to the variables declared before instantiating the groovy shell.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this... but it may work:

```
new GroovyShell(this.binding).evaluate(line)
```

or this:

```
new GroovyShell(new Binding(this.binding.variables)).evaluate(line)
```